# Should I really edit Titles

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, titles, hot-questions-list

I noticed that $\LaTeX$ is not used in title of  following question

> [Prove that $1 + 4 + 7 + · · · + 3n − 2 = \frac {n(3n − 1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050814/prove-that-1-4-7-3n-%E2%88%92-2-n3n-%E2%88%92-1-2)

Before I click edit button, I noticed that it has received over $2000$ views, I checked Hot network questions, and it was there

[image]

I, therefore decided to keep it as it is. Was it a good decision to make, If not please Let me know and I'll edit it.

> Edit: The question was edited! End of popularity!

Comment: Why are you requesting that others don't edit it?

Comment: @JonasMeyer [Just for fun!](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=month)

Comment: You're 47 edits behind, better stop wasting time on meta!

Comment: @JonasMeyer Now $43$

Comment: There were some related discussion on this site, you might have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/title-formatting-of-latex-in-stackexchange-hot-questions-list), or on some of questions from [this search](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[mathjax]+hot).

Comment: You could undo the title edit. :) But on the other hand, maybe it got enough minutes of fame already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I really edit Titles

**In general**: yes, you should, along with everything else. When needed. Too often, editors overlook the title when fixing a post. Here's a suggested edit I saw just now:

[image: edit]

---

**In your example**, the title is perfectly readable, even if the lining numbers in Georgia are not to everyone's liking.  I would leave it be; there are far worse things around.

Hot List is not the primary consideration here, but as long as the question is not embarrassment, having it there is slightly better than not having it. More people will learn something about induction as a result.

Related:

- [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles?lq=1)
- [Should latex be discouraged in titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/should-latex-be-discouraged-in-titles?lq=1)